# Issue with printing Arabic text using ReadexPro Variable font

Tags: c#, itext

I am having trouble printing Arabic text using the ReadexPro Varaible font. The text comes up as blank.

Note: I'm using iTextSharp, not iText7

Here's the code for creating the font

```
public static readonly BaseFont ReadexBaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(Path.Combine(WWWROOT_PATH, "ReadexPro-VariableFont_wght.ttf"), BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

public static readonly Font ReadexLightBlack = new(ReadexBaseFont,5f, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
```

I have tried checking if the font supports Arabic characters and the character encoding of the file,but the issue still appears.

Comment: Did you try with non Arabic text to see if this is related to Arabic specifically?

Comment: yes, this issue is only regarding Arabic text in specific,